# Jenkins doesn't allow file moving in post build task?

Tags: jenkins

Using Jenkins, in a post-build task, I execute batch commands. I had some file to move there using command `move` in the script. The files to be moved is the whole workspace, I loop through the files.

However, when Jenkins execute the `move` command in post-build task, it says access is denied when trying to move the file from command line. I guess Jenkins probably protects the files at this point. This code execution really needs to be there for a special task.

My assumption is that in post build task Jenkins locks the workspace, but that prevents from doing some things. Is there a way to still move file in the post-build task?

Comment: What are you trying to move? Build artifacts?

Comment: Which type of post-build action do you use? Please consider considering [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) This is one of two of your questions within the last three days that lacks useful information.

Comment: @BrunoLavit Updated the question

Comment: Thanks for the update, so you want to move all the files included in the Jenkins workspace? If the answer is yes, the only solution will be to call a downstream job which will move the files of the upstream job. But this is not a "classical" practice...

Comment: I see... thanks for the quick answer. So from what I understand it's a normal Jenkins comportment to lock the files like this?

Comment: Jenkins does not lock files.  If you're getting access violations, you should be considering the file permissions from Jenkins account perspective, as well as file locking issues at the operating system level.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my problem was the way I was moving file, they were locked by another command. It had nothing to do with Jenkins.

See [how to move folders with a loop over folders (in batch)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548438/how-to-move-folders-with-a-loop-over-folders-in-batch)