# how to move folders with a loop over folders (in batch)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

**Situation:**

I try to move files inside a loop in shell but my code is not working.

```
for /D %%F in (*) do (
   if "%%F" NEQ "%directoryToPutFilesIn%" (
     move /y "%%F" "%directoryToPutFilesIn%"
  )
)
```

After hours of testing it, I realized it's because %%F is pointing to the folder, hence the file cannot be moved.

**Bad solution:**

The way I made it work and confirmed my suspicions is by saving the value of %%F in another variable and using that variable on next turn to move the file. Note, what is following needs an initialisation of `%precedentFile%` for the first turn.

```
for /D %%F in (*) do (
move /y "%precedentFile%" "%directoryToPutFilesIn%"
   if "%%F" NEQ "%directoryToPutFilesIn%" (
     move /y "%%F" "%directoryToPutFilesIn%"
     set precedentFile=%%F
  )
```

**Problem:**

This solution is not practical and feels wrongs. Is there a way to adapt my current code to do it, or simply another way?

Comment: Are you trying to move just folders, or also `.txt` files etc..?

Comment: I have 2 loops, the one I showed is for folder. I have another one almost the same for files. Both don't work.

Comment: try below code to move files and folders, hope that helps  :)  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to move files from one folder to another in batch script:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /a:-D /b') do move /Y "%%~fa" "%directoryToPutFilesIn%"
```

Explanation :

```
dir /a:-D /b : This command will list all files in the directory 
move /Y "%%~fa" "%directoryToPutFilesIn%" : This will move all files in the directory where this command is executed to the destination you have mentioned.
%%~fa : This command will get full qualified path of the file with it's name.
```

Try Below code Move directories :
Below command will move directories in the Path where this command is executed to the destination provided. In this that will be H:\ Drive, Change it accordingly

```
for /D %%b in (*) do move /Y "%%~fb" "H:\"
```

Comment: I get the following error : The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~fa"

Comment: actually I added a % before the variable and it works. I'm not able to edit it. I'll mark it as answer. Do you know why it takes 2 % ?

Comment: if you are executing above command directly in command line it works fine , but if you want them in batch script you need to use an extra "%" for using variable value. This is by design ..

Comment: changed my answer , please accept if you found this helpful , so that others can use.

Comment: Accepted it. Thanks a lot for the specification about double percent, now I get it!!!