# Recursively search for FOLDERS from list and move

Tags: batch-file

Need help with searching all sub folders. The current script works fine but only in the top directory. Any help?

```
md "C:\users\%username%\desktop\People"
SET LOGFILE=C:\users\%username%\desktop\movelog.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in (people.txt) do (
    move "%%i" C:\users\%username%\desktop\People >nul 2>&1
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%i : Move failed >> %LOGFILE%%
    ) else (
        echo %%i : Move successful >> %LOGFILE%
    )
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only in the top directory?" It should take the file `people.txt` and attempt to move all of files named in that file to `...\people` What does it do that you don't want it to do or not do that you expect it to do? A sample of `people.txt` may be helpful.

Comment: It works only in the root folder. I need it to search sub-folder also. The people.txt has one name for each line.

Comment: e.g. line 1 = Tom Sawyer, line 2 = Huckleberry Finn. The script moves folders not files.

Comment: Apologies...  The script moves files but in my case I'm searching for and moving folders.

Comment: Take a look at this ==> [how to move folders with a loop over folders (in batch)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548438/how-to-move-folders-with-a-loop-over-folders-in-batch)

Comment: Your `logfile` path and `target folder` path needs to be double quoted else a name with a space etc can break it, and there is a double `%%` typo there.   Your task needs to move a folder called `Tom Sawyer` from any folder level to the `people` folder, right?  What should happen if there is more than one `Tom Sawyer` folder somewhere there in the tree?

Comment: Hackoo... no luck with searching sub-folders within that post I could see.

Comment: foxidrive... There is no double named folders within the tree, I'm certain. Yes, from any folder level down from which the script is executed. I can't figure how to search sub-folders with out breaking the script as is. If all the "name" folders are in a single folder it works but that is not the way I have it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: im assuming the log file is the list that you want directories to be recursively searched against?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that im reading your question correctly, you want to be able to use the script from any location to find a folder thats specified within your text file to be moved to the new location correct? On linux machines a simple `find * "foldername"|grep "foldername"` would present usable code to find the files your looking for. Windows does have something similar but not nearly as easy as the linux version.

You can use the following code `dir \ /A:D /B /S /O:G|find "%%i"` to search for the folder recursively. However the code will output ALL instances of the particular string thats passed to it, which includes the file path for EVERYTHING thats in the particular folders contents. What you would be asking is to move all folders under that name to the new location.

Because of this, **there needs to be some sort of identifier in each users folder as so to let the sorting program know that this is what im looking for and nothing else.** If i had a blank text file labeled marker.txt in all the particular folders, i can run the code as `dir \ /B /S|find "%%i\marker.txt"` and this provides a unique marker for the searching program to identify with. This can be stored and sorted later into a variable so for example i had a marker.txt I can then run a simple `set path=dir \ /B /S|find "%%i\marker"`, and make the new movement variable as `move %path%\..`. So unless you have a file that is commonly shared by all of these, you may find it difficult to sort them.